# How do I use a Kotlin function from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, interop

I wrote a Kotlin program, called `hw.kt`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     println("hello world")    
}
```

I want to use Kotlin functions in my Java code, as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html), but after compiling and trying to use `HwKt` in Java, Java complains that it can't find `HwKt`. I tried using a package name in the Kotlin file and importing `org.example.*`, which doesn't work either.

Simply compiling the Kotlin file (without a package name) and calling "HwKt.main" in Java results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    HwKt cannot be resolved

    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

For what it's worth, using a Java class in another Java file works fine.

Comment: What is the package your main method is in? Where do you call it from? How do you compile? (IDE/gradle/maven/by hand). Eclipse is known to have some troubles mixing Kotlin and Java at runtime when combined with build tools (compiling should be fine).

Comment: I'm compiling by hand.

Comment: By hand, sure. So try to locate both the class file compiled for your kotlin file and the Java file. Found both? Then please update with more details of the error message. If not found, please fix compilation.